# Partial FTP upload with storbinary

Tags: python, ftp

I'm sending a xml file over ftp to the server but it cuts off at 48KB out of 53KB.

The code is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    ftp = ftplib.FTP("IP")
    ftp.login(user = 'NAME', passwd = 'PASS')
    ftp.cwd('/web/content/tree/_demo') 
    a.write('<root>\n' + DirXML(dirname) + '\n</root>')
    f=open(outputname,'rb')
    ftp.storbinary('STOR '+os.path.basename(outputname),f)
    f.close()
    ftp.quit()
```

The same problem as this: [Partial Upload With storbinary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670084/partial-upload-with-storbinary-in-python)
But of course that doesn't supply an answer. The file sends via ftp client, sends via python interpreter but not via the script.

edit: It throws no exceptions, completes fine but when I look at the uploaded file it is cut off at the end. If I remove the ftp part and have the file export to my local computer it comes out fine. The indents were just me being bad at formatting.

Comment: have you tried manually transferring file to the server, to make sure that it's python's fault?

Comment: Yeah, definitely something in my code.

Comment: so, is it `storbinary` or `storlines`? also, what is `a` and how is it related to your code?`

Comment: Sorry, tried storlines with the same effect and forgot to change it when I posted the expanded code.

    outputname = (dirname + ".xml")
    a = open(outputname, "w")

Comment: why don't you close `a` first, and then start reading from it?

Comment: If I use a.close(), I get a I/O error that I can't read from a closed file with open or readlines. Am I just doing this wrong?

Comment: When you say cuts off, what happens? Does it throw an exception?

Also, why is some of your code indented? Do you have more complete code and the result?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `storlines` instead of `storbinary`.

The former will do line end translation.

The `storbinary` ftplib code does a `TYPE I` before the transfer to ensure that the transfer mode is set to Image. (Binary).

Also check to ensure that the file you are transferring has been flushed or closed before the transfer begins.  The data written through the `write` call may not be flushed to disk at the point where the ftp library opens the file.